# Why don't my nested divs look nested?

Tags: html, css

I have placed one div inside of another, but it keeps appearing below the div it is nested inside.  What I want is to get the login div to appear inside the navdiv but push it over to the right of the page. 
I can get it over there by adding position absolute, (which I'm also unsure about) but it then behaves in ways I don't want when I resize the page.

Please try to explain what is happening here as simply as possible. Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/viggie/5we2wxug/

```
#navdiv {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#navdiv li {
  background-color: red;
  display :inline;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left:35px;
  margin-right:35px;
  margin-bottom:4px;
}
#navdiv li a:visited {
  color: yellow;
}
#navdiv li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#login {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#login li {
  verticle-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div id="navdiv">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://codepen.io/viggie/pen/ragPVG">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.yahoo.com">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.espn.com">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPBRqp">Join</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="login">
      <ul>
        <li>Log out</li>
        <li>Log in</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove `height` in `#navdiv` css and add `overflow:auto` will contain all the menu items inside the `#navdiv`

Comment: Ah thats doing more like what I want it to do.  Looking up overflow auto though all it talks about is creating a scroll bar when text cant fit inside of a div.  Why does this put the div inside of the div?  Also why do I need to tell it this at all, I have nested the div inside of the other div, shouldn't it automatically be placed inside?  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: To remove horizontal scroll, add `overflow-x:hidden;` to `#navdiv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your `#login` div is technically inside of `#navdiv`, `#navdiv` has a `height` set which is stopping the background from extending to cover the `#login` as well - The `#login` is inside it structurally, but visually it's overflowing the `#navdiv` area.

So, to stop that bit, simply remove the `height` from `#navdiv`.

To align the login to the right, I'd recommend making the `#login ul` an `inline-block` that's simply aligned `right`. You lose the `absolute` and`float` issues, and it's easy to make responsive.

```
#login {
    text-align: right;
}
#login ul {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note, I also put the background color on the `ul` since it's more accurate to the `#login` area - probably you'll want to modify the styling some yet anyways.

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/5we2wxug/1/

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your css

```
.left_part { float:left;width:72%;}
.right_part { float:right;width:28%;}
.right_part ul { padding-left:0px;}
```

and add this in body part

```
 <div id="navdiv">
    <div class="left_part">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="http://codepen.io/viggie/pen/ragPVG">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="www.yahoo.com">Members</a></li>
              <li><a href="www.espn.com">Articles</a></li>
              <li><a href="www.google.com">Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPBRqp">Join</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <div class="right_part">
            <ul>
                  <li>Log out</li>
                  <li>Log in</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

i just gave you normal idea and now i hope you can manage your own css with this way...hope it helps..

**Updated**

according to you...just use Float in ul and in login div as login div will not go with ul until you are not using float left or right properties..they have their own css and you have to use float for this...there can be more option but float will help you in your case if you don't want more div..

Comment: I understand what youre trying to do with this solution.  My real question though is why cant I simply put one div inside my other div?  Why is it showing up below the first div instead of inside of it?

Comment: Because you are not using float..check my updated ans.

Comment: but if you are going with float then you will have to use clear and some other properties too...be careful with float...